# Fluids: stuck inside obstacle

Tags: fluid-simulation

Okay, I have a fluid stuck inside one of my obstacles. I made sure to get the inflow outside of said obstacle so it doesn't collide with it. I intended for this fluid to flow into a small pool and then overflow into a larger one.

Here's the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1dIaL3qkRdQYjhYYklFNzZWSWc/view?usp=sharing

I'd give a picture, but I have lunch right now.

Now I ended up with this:
http://prntscr.com/9p5fx2

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things you need to change to make it work.

1. Your fluid domain needs to be a box.
2. Your spherical inflow object vectors are all set to zero. Give it some value.

**NOTE** With vector of Zero on (X,Y,Z) your inflow will be manifested as slow drips of water.

Here are my tests.

[image]
[image]

**Download here for your reference.**

[image]

Comment: I did those two things, and got this: http://prntscr.com/9p5fx2

Comment: Okay, so I was able to fix that leaking issue: the domain needs to enclose every single obstacle in the simulation.

However, there's still the issue of how the fluid interacts with the obstacles. Mainly the spring and how it's interacting with the fluid. Firstly, the fluid is still going inside the obstacle. It's not leaking out or getting stuck, but it's still getting into the fluid. Here's an image on this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1dIaL3qkRdQTEtCVDRPQW1FMDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1dIaL3qkRdQX3R0VHRFM2NNY28/view?usp=sharing
There's also this issue. The fluid isn't really landing on the ground, or ends up leaking through it, as seen in this image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1dIaL3qkRdQMGcxTk1SQmxLejg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I might be compel to think that the scale of object in your scene seems to be giantic. The rock that spills water is approximately 16 meters tall in blender units. Scale is a important factor when dealing with simulation.

Comment: .blend file is broken, after multiple saves. I think it's corrupted now.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1dIaL3qkRdQM2U5a09Yd0pUQXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Or, it could just be blender itself, since I downloaded your file, and wasn't able to bake it either.

Comment: My blender version is 2.75 , if it helps at all.